# how to make bot respond to if there is more then four uppercase letter in message.content discord.py

Tags: discord, discord.py

Please help me out I tried doing this but I don't know what's wrong with my code, it didn't work.

```py
msgs_up=message.content.upper

msg_count=msgs_up.count(msgs_up,0,200)

if ( msg_count >= 4 ):
  await message.channel.send('Woah woah. stop the cap')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions to find the number of capital letters in a string.

```py
import re

regex = "[A-Z]" # Matches only capital letters

string1 = "Not too many caps here"
string2 = "FULL of CAPS"
```

Use the `findall` method to get all matches

```py
>>> re.findall(regex, string1)
['N']

>>> re.findall(regex, string2)
['F', 'U', 'L', 'L', 'C', 'A', 'P', 'S']
```

This returns a `list` containing all matches. You can now check if the string contains more than four capital letters by checking if the length of the list is greater than 4.

However, note that it is often better to check if a percentage of letters is capital rather than a fixed amount.

```py
>>> string3 = "This string might appear to not contain too many Capital Letters. But, it still triggers the response since the number of Capital Letters is greater than 4.

>>> re.findall(regex, string3)
['T', 'C', 'L', 'B', 'C', 'L'] # 6 capital letters
```